# How can I bring an excellentable data in the Confluence page?

Tags: rest, confluence, unirest

I have to bring data using unirest from the Confluence page.
But, data consisted in Excellentable of kind of web excel.
As below code, if using asString() or asJson then return html tab + script sources.
Please, Tell me how to bring data from Excellentable.
Thanks.

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get(strConUrl)
                      .basicAuth(userId, userPw)
                      .header("Accept", "application/json")
                      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                      .asString();


HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get(strConUrl)
                      .basicAuth(userId, userPw)
                      .header("Accept", "application/json")
                      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                      .asJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use REST API to get pages body data: https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/rest/8.0.2/. In this way you can get "clean" text or HTML/xHTML as you need.